# unable to connect to subversion via subclipse

Tags: svn, eclipse

I am trying eclipse helios on windows 64 bit and I have tried subclipse 1.6 & 1.8 but I have not been able to get it to work.  The most recent error message is copied below:

```
    RA layer request failed
svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://dev-repo.test.com'
svn: The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at line 1: no element found (https://dev-repo.test.com)
```

I can access the repo using svn checkout in the command line as well as in the browser.

Any thoughts on how best to resolve the issue?

Comment: pilot error -had the wrong URL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a localized issue only applicable to the OP and unlikely to assist future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try giving the absolute URL of the repo instead of 'https://dev-repo.test.com'

Comment: thanks - I tried that before you responded.  That was the issue on my part.